# How to set cookie for one hour with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to set cookie for one hour with JavaScript?

I've try this :

```
 var now = new Date(); 
    now.setTime(now.getTime() + 1 * 3600 * 1000);
    document.cookie = "Mycookie=true; expires=" + now.toUTCString() + "; path=/";

   var cookieExists = document.cookie.indexOf('Mycookie=');//will return -1 if cookie not exists 

   console.log(cookieExists);
```

but it's always return me -1.

So, I guesses I write something wrong.

Comment: facing issue on Chrome + localhost ?

Comment: I've had issues before with cookies not showing up in `document.cookie`. Don't remember anymore why that was. Check if they show up in the dev tools under Application -> Storage -> Cookies.

Comment: Some browsers may not accept writing cookies with http protocol. Your code is ok. Try use local storage instead

Comment: Try setting maxAge: 3600 and secure: false